# PostGIS: Spatial Index not being used

Tags: postgis, spatial-index

Below is the query I'm using :

```
SELECT osm_id FROM planet_osm_line where ST_DWITHIN((ST_Transform(way,4326)), st_setsrid(ST_Point(9.17193, 48.76768),4326) ,50000)
and time_cost =0.1 limit 100000;
```

I did `Explain`, I see that the index on geom column `way` is not being used.

I've two indexes, on `time_cost` and `way`

Below is the trace on Explain:

```
  Limit  (cost=0.43..245639.85 rows=2975 width=8) (actual time=0.510..1360.168 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using time_cost_idx on planet_osm_line  (cost=0.43..245639.85 rows=2975 width=8) (actual time=0.509..1322.503 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (time_cost = '0.1'::double precision)
         Filter: ((st_transform(way, 4326) && '0103000020E610000001000000050000001AA88C7FDA68E8C0475A2A6FE763E8C01AA88C7FDA68E8C0B9A5D5901870E840E6577380256BE840B9A5D5901870E840E6577380256B
E840475A2A6FE763E8C01AA88C7FDA68E8C0475A2A6FE763E8C0'::geometry) AND ('0101000020E61000000E677E35075822408AE5965643624840'::geometry && st_expand(st_transform(way, 4326), '50000'::double pr
ecision)) AND _st_dwithin(st_transform(way, 4326), '0101000020E61000000E677E35075822408AE5965643624840'::geometry, '50000'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.284 ms
 Execution time: 1377.343 ms
(6 rows)
```

Hers is the updated trace after adding index as suggested:

```
 Limit  (cost=33699.36..183915.21 rows=2975 width=8) (actual time=639.022..2008.438 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on planet_osm_line  (cost=33699.36..183915.21 rows=2975 width=8) (actual time=639.020..1971.429 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((time_cost = '0.1'::double precision) AND (st_transform(way, 4326) && '0103000020E610000001000000050000001AA88C7FDA68E8C0475A2A6FE763E8C01AA88C7FDA68E8C0B9A5D59018
70E840E6577380256BE840B9A5D5901870E840E6577380256BE840475A2A6FE763E8C01AA88C7FDA68E8C0475A2A6FE763E8C0'::geometry))
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 107717
         Filter: (('0101000020E61000000E677E35075822408AE5965643624840'::geometry && st_expand(st_transform(way, 4326), '50000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(st_transform(way, 4326),
'0101000020E61000000E677E35075822408AE5965643624840'::geometry, '50000'::double precision))
         Heap Blocks: exact=15297 lossy=32836
         ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=33699.36..33699.36 rows=44623 width=0) (actual time=629.404..629.404 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on time_cost_idx  (cost=0.00..4169.81 rows=223117 width=0) (actual time=40.065..40.065 rows=252522 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (time_cost = '0.1'::double precision)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on geom_way_line_idx  (cost=0.00..29527.82 rows=651121 width=0) (actual time=580.924..580.924 rows=3255604 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (st_transform(way, 4326) && '0103000020E610000001000000050000001AA88C7FDA68E8C0475A2A6FE763E8C01AA88C7FDA68E8C0B9A5D5901870E840E6577380256BE840B9A5D5901870E
840E6577380256BE840475A2A6FE763E8C01AA88C7FDA68E8C0475A2A6FE763E8C0'::geometry)
 Planning time: 0.230 ms
 Execution time: 2025.651 ms
(13 rows)
```

Comment: You're not querying on the geometry column, so the geometry index ***shouldn't*** be used. Try building a covering index on the cast of the ST_Transfom output to geography, then using explicit casts to geography on the first two ST_DWithin parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `way` is not used directly, there is little use for an index on it. You can try to add a new index on `ST_Transform(way,4326)`

Comment: do I need to Vacuum Analyze after that bcos it is not being used either :(

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Somehow the performance got worse after adding the above mentioned index

Comment: @gameOne show the new query plan..

Comment: @EvanCarroll Edited with new query plan

Comment: @gameOne we need the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of both.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I added some data to it maybe that's why the change. Edited it now for same query and same data but with both index results